# CD4066B switches in parallel to lower Ron

Tags: cmos, parallel, analog-switch

In a music synthesizer design, I use two [CD4066B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b-mil.pdf) gates (with complementary control) to switch on or off a VCO control voltage.
One is in series with the control voltage and the other connects the input to ground when the control voltage is disconnected.

As there are two unused 4066B  switches, may I parallel them to the others to get a lower Ron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *As there are two unused 4066B switches, may I parallel them to the
> others to get a lower Ron?*

There are at least three options

1. Parallel both spare switches with the series switch to get lower series "on" resistance
2. Parallel both spare switches with the shorting switch to get lower resistance to GND/0 volts when "off"
3. Parallel to both switches (probably not much benefit)

Other options: -

- You can also use the spare switches in series arrangements should "off" coupling of high frequency signals be a particular problem.
- You can use a two stage on/off switch (two banks of on/off wired in cascade).

Comment: The two stage cascade is a very good idea, I'll use it for my design, as it needs a very low leakage when control voltage is off.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to 'improve' an existing situation, it's best to be explicit about what's wrong with it.

Are you lacking isolation when the switch is off?
Are you lacking signal level when the switch is on?
Are you getting distortion when the switch is on?
Are you getting crosstalk from 'off' channels when the switch is on?

Each defect may require a different switch having another element put in series or parallel with it, or the switch topology changing entirely, to best fix the problem.

If none of the above are true, then save your time and solder!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can certainly parallel them to reduce Ron (and therefore also Ron changes which can cause distortion).

The 'off' coupling will be doubled as will things like capacitance and leakages. If you double up on both switches the net effect on off coupling will not change much.